# R: dplyr for loop to get summaries by column

Tags: r, dplyr

How do you write a `dplyr` `for` loop that will provide summaries for each column of a `data.table` object?

Let's examine a toy example to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve and what I have tried. We have 5 variables:

```
str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I can get a summary of counts by distinct `Sepal.Length` like so:

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
    summarise(no_rows = length(Sepal.Length))

# A tibble: 35 x 2
   Sepal.Length no_rows
          <dbl>   <int>
 1         4.30       1
 2         4.40       3
 3         4.50       1
 4         4.60       4
 5         4.70       2
 6         4.80       5
 7         4.90       6
 8         5.00      10
 9         5.10       9
10         5.20       4
# ... with 25 more rows
```

I would like to write the above in a `for` loop that loops through each of the 5 variables in the data frame. I started by replacing `Sepal.Length` above with: `paste(names(iris)[1])`.

```
iris %>%
  group_by( paste(names(iris)[1]) ) %>%
  summarise(no_rows = length( paste(names(iris)[1])) )
```

But I get:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `names(design_mat4)[1]` no_rows
  <chr>                     <int>
1 email_status                  1
```

Is there a better way of achieving my aims, perhaps one that avoids a `for` loop? Are there leads or suggestions that I can follow to write a working `for` loop? Code or suggestions welcome.

Not sure if it matters, but please note that I am working with a `data.table` object while the above toy example is a `data.frame` object. I know that there are nuances between the two that may impact the syntax needed.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the results in a list

```
lapply(names(iris), 
       function(var){
          iris %>%
            group_by(rlang::sym(var)) %>%
            summarise(no_rows = n())
})
```

Here's a better `dplyr` answer from @Frank

```
lapply(names(iris) %>% setNames(.,.), function(var) iris %>% count(!!as.name(var)))
```

And a `data.table` answer

```
lapply(names(iris) %>% setNames(.,.), function(x) as.data.table(iris)[, .(n = .N), by = x])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or do it in base R.

```
lapply(iris, function(x) aggregate(x, by = list(x), length))
```

Answer (score 1):

If all variables are of the same type, a simpler way to approach the problem is to reshape to long form:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
    select(-Species) %>% 
    gather(variable, value) %>% 
    count(variable, value)
#> # A tibble: 123 x 3
#>    variable     value     n
#>    <chr>        <dbl> <int>
#>  1 Petal.Length  1.00     1
#>  2 Petal.Length  1.10     1
#>  3 Petal.Length  1.20     2
#>  4 Petal.Length  1.30     7
#>  5 Petal.Length  1.40    13
#>  6 Petal.Length  1.50    13
#>  7 Petal.Length  1.60     7
#>  8 Petal.Length  1.70     4
#>  9 Petal.Length  1.90     2
#> 10 Petal.Length  3.00     1
#> # ... with 113 more rows
```

If you include `Species`, the `value` column will be coerced to character, though.